# Pandas shuffle years in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following dataset:

```
             0         1
0    1996-01-01  0.556341
1    1996-01-02  1.266325
...         ...       ...
367  1997-01-01  1.175108
368  1997-01-02  1.111937
369  1997-01-03  1.018124
...         ...       ...
8396 2018-12-27  2.016161
8397 2018-12-28  2.031135
8398 2018-12-29  2.008132
8399 2018-12-30  2.416433
```

What I first want to is to shuffle the years (1996-2018), so that they are in random order e.g. [1997,2000,2015,...]

Afterward, I would like to reorder the rows to the same order of the shuffled years, so the result might look like this:

```
             0         1
0    1997-01-01  1.175108
1    1997-01-02  1.111937
...         ...       ...
367  2018-01-01  2.2821236
368  2018-01-02  2.0624123
369  2018-01-03  2.5721483
...         ...       ...
8396 1996-12-27  1.7438917
8397 1996-12-28  1.8455334
8398 1996-12-29  1.6793785
8399 1996-12-30  1.6234837
```

Is there any elegant way of doing this?
One idea I came up with is creating a new dataframe and appending the years in the new order to it, but this doesn't seem to be really efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
from random import shuffle

df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])  # Just in case

ydfs = [ydf for _, ydf in df.groupby(df[0].dt.year)]
shuffle(ydfs)
df = pd.concat(ydfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Works fantastic. Thank yo so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=true)
```

The [sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) will return a random sample of items of the axis and frac=1 means sample the whole axis.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in getting totally random samples? As mentioned in the question: I would like to preserve the order of the days within the year itself.